# how could I get value with checkbox via serialize?

Tags: php, ajax

how could I get value with checkbox via serialize?

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"account_ing",
data:$("#editform_account input:checkbox").serialize(),
cache:false,
success:function(data){
$("#loading").html(data);
}
});
```

I have 2 checkboxes totally

and I can get the values are: On (if those checkboxes are Checked) From account_ing side

But my checkbox has value are: 1

How could I get the checkbox value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide your desired value in input checkbox html like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="1" />
```

In Jquery:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").val();    // will give you the assigned value ie 1
```

In case you are using serialize() than also it will give 1, if checked.